# Добавить класс к созданному контенту на странице

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть такой кусок кода:

```
element.closest('.comment').after(commentItem)
```

Он добавляет некоторое содержимое **commentItem(содержит HTML)** после элемента **element**
Содержимое представляет собой блок Div, как к этому созданному блоку добавить новый класс?

Comment: > commentItem(содержит HTML)

В этот html и добавьте атрибут class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
element.closest('.comment').after($('<div>The test</div>').addClass(class))
```

или

```
$('<div>The test</div>').insertAfter(element.closest('.comment')).addClass(class)
```